# Strange result when trying to print

Tags: c

After execution, result was very strange:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int a,b; 
  printf("enter two numbers :");
  scanf("%d%d",&a,&b);
  if(a>b){
    printf("maximum number is %d",&a);
  } 
  else{
    printf("maximum number is %d",&b);  
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

After enter two numbers in console result was:

```
maximum number is 2686696
```

**2686696 very strange** for me if I enter two numbers such as 5, 3 must shows me 5 but shows 2686696 !!!

Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `&` from `printf` to print the value, now you're printing the address. Should be:

```
printf("maximum number is %d",a);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to print the address of `int` not its value. Do this:

```
if(a>b){
    printf("maximum number is %d",a);
}
else{
    printf("maximum number is %d",b);  
}
```

`&` operator returns the address of `a` or `b`.

Answer (score 0):

The & in printf prints the address of the variables instead of the value.

To print a value use :

```
if(a>b){
   printf("maximum number is %d",a);
}
else{
    printf("maximum number is %d",b);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `&` operator from the argument of `printf` if you are interested in printing the numbers `a` and `b` else change the format specifier `%d` to `%p` if you are trying to print the address of `a` and `b`.

```
printf("maximum number is %p", (void *)&a);
```